# set cursor focus in native textField, corona sdk

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm trying to set cursor focus in TextField created with native library, but I can't. please if any one have an idea for this, I will appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use to set focus:

```
native.setKeyboardFocus( passwordField )
```

and use this to take the focus away:

```
native.setKeyboardFocus( nil )
```

It should be included in submitted call for the corresponding textfield.